# Oracle sql query to pick current and previous records

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, oracle11g, query-performance

I have a table that contains all transactions with Quantity column. Need to calculate the cumulative total of quantity of transaction group and update in each transaction row.

TRANSACTION table:

```
 id(PK) group_id, txn_id, txn_date,   Quantity, cumulative_qty    
  1            1      111     12-AUG-14    10            10
  2            1      112     13-AUG-14    -5             5  
  3            1      113     14-AUG-14     2             7
  4            2      221     23-AUG-14    15            15   
  5            2      222     23-AUG-14    15            30
```

I wrote MERGE INTO script and it is working file. But the problem is that it is updating old records also. This table is having huge volume of data and that hit is performance issue.

Now I need a merge script that need to fetch only unprocessed new records (cumulative_qty is NULL) and add the Quantity with last cumulative_qty value.

Suppose, if there is any new transactions for the same group, the select of merge should pick up old and new records alone and update the new record.

```
id(PK) group_id, txn_id, txn_date,     Quantity, cumulative_qty    
  6            1      114     25-AUG-14     5             NULL
  7            2      223     25-AUG-14    -10            NULL
```

I am using Oracle 11g. Please help me on writing a logic in a single MERGE sql query?

Comment: Last in what context?Per day,per group_id?

Comment: Your table has to txn_id columns. What does that mean?

Comment: @Mihai latest txn. in this case id 6 & 7 rows are latest records that need to be processed. For this, my sql query need to consider only row 3,5,6,7 only.

Comment: can anyone help in fine tuning @Laurence query to get only 4 rows for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key idea is using the `lag` window function to get the previous cumulative quantity.

using `merge`:

```
merge into
  txn t1
using (
  select
    txn_id,
    lag(cumulative_qty, 1) over (
      partition by group_id 
      order by txn_id
    ) as prev_cum_qty
  from
    txn
  ) x
on
  (t1.txn_id = x.txn_id)
when matched then update set
  cumulative_qty = quantity + prev_cum_qty
where
  cumulative_qty is null;
```

[Example using Merge](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4517a4/5)

Or as an `update` statement:

```
update
  txn t1
set
  cumulative_qty = quantity + (
    select prev_cum_qty from (
      select
        txn_id,
        lag(cumulative_qty, 1) over (
          partition by group_id 
          order by txn_id
        ) as prev_cum_qty
      from
        txn t2
      ) x
    where
        t1.txn_id = x.txn_id
  ) 
where
  cumulative_qty is null;
```

[Example using Update](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4517a4/1)

Comment: Hi @Laurence. Thanks for the merge query. It is working fine. One thing with performance perspective is that the select query returns all 7 rows to process and then merge 2 rows. But I want the select query that should return only 4 rows (id-3,5,6,7) i.e. the last cumulative row (order by max date and id) and unprocessed rows only.

Comment: @SureshRajagopal You could experiment with putting the where clause inside the in-line view, but I thought there might be a fencepost error. Would be pretty simple for you to test.